# Translate custom module admin panel in magento backend

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, translation, magento-1.4

Greetings!

I am trying to create a module for a client that can be translated into many languages. I have created CSV files to translate the frontend, but I cannot find a way to translate my options in the configuration page of the backend. I assume it has something to do with my system.xml file but I cannot find a solution. Anyone have any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

All that you need is to write in your custom module configuration file (config.xml):

```
<config>
    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Custom_Module>
                    <files>
                        <default>Custom_Module.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Custom_Module>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

And locate your Custom_Module.csv into app/locale/lang_code/ folder.